# List initialisation in a class constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm new to C++ and how to make constructor for a vector confused me so much. I have a class like this:

```
class myClass{
public:
    myClass();
    ......
private:
    std::vector<double> myVariable;
    ......
}
```

and I want to write a constructor for

```
myClass{1.2, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0};
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Use a member initializer list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a constructor that accepts a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
explicit myClass(std::initializer_list<double> init) : myVariable(init) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a vector, insert elements to it, pass it to the `myClass` constructor, which assigns it to the class member vector:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(const std::vector<double> &src)
        : myVariable(src)
    {
    }

    private:
        std::vector<double> myVariable;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> myvect{1.2, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0};
    myClass obj(myvect);
}
```

Comment: The class constructor should take the input vector by const reference to avoid making an unnecessary copy, and also use the constructor initialization list instead of assignment in the constructor body. However, `std::vector<double> myvect(1.2, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0);` will not compile, as `vector` has no such constructor. You would have to put the values into an array and then use the vector constructor that accepts an iterator range. Or you would have to construct an empty vector and then `push_back()` the individual values. Also, you are leaking `obj`.

Comment: thank you Remy for your suggestion but, it is just an idea that how it can be implemented. The code is not written for compilation purpose.

Comment: if it is not meant to compile, it is not a viable answer. I have corrected the mistakes for you.